# Ranking in Excel using Dates but account for duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I tried to look at other questions on ranking but nothing specifically address my problem or maybe I may be coming up short in trying to apply other solutions to my problem.

I have a column of names (staff) and their corresponding dates of appointment(DoA) and I would try to rank these staff in order of appointment dates in essence if John Doe started working on the 1st of January 2021 and Bob Snow started on the 2nd of January 2021. Then John Doe will have a rank of 1 and Bob Snow a Rank of 2.

I have used the formula below to give me a rank

`=RANK(@[DoA], [DoA], 1)`

The problem is because the dates are in `DateTime` format and some of the dates are the same, I have duplicate values in my ranking.

How do I go about ensuring that my ranking outputs unique values?

Answer (score 0):

The solution already exists online see [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-without-ties) and [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2512-excel-unique-rank.html#:%7E:text=In%20Microsoft%20Excel%2C%20the%20normal,this%20will%20skip%20some%20numbers.). I guess my major problem was trying to implement this in a table (i.e. structured referencing).

The solution is:

```
= RANK([@[DoA]], [DoA], 1) + COUNTIF($C$2:[@[DoA]], [@[DoA]])-1
```

***Note that C2 is the cell reference of the first cell under the DoA column header***